# c++ && <= float and if

Tags: c++, if-statement, floating-point, int

when I use:

```
if( a>=0 && a<100 && b>=0 && b<200 )
```

everything works fine but if I use:

```
if( 0<=a<100 && 0<=b<200 )
```

my program crashes. a and b = floats. Can somebody please tell me what's the difference?

Comment: Try posting code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Well, in this case you should write: if 0<=a<100 and 0<=b<200

Comment: a < b < c  is a common abbreviation in maths , but is not supported in the way you intend in c++.  You have to use the syntax in the first example.

Comment: C++ doesn't mind doing it, but it doesn't do what you'd think.  Basically it'd take the bool result from one of the operations, convert it to an int, and compare against that.

Comment: well, it's about accessing pixels with OpenCV, a and b would be x and y coordinates.

Comment: I'm guessing it crashes because the condition evaluates to true even when a and b are out of range and there's probably resulting a memory access issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`0<=a<100` is actually `(0<=a)<100`. Since `(0<=a)` is a boolean, its value is always either 0 or 1 (true or false), therefore the expression becomes `0<100` (or `1<100`), which is always true.

Since you are sort-of indexing an array with `a` and `b`, the wrong bounds check leads to, well, an out-of-bounds access, which crashes your application.

Comment: So, naturally, it would crash?

Comment: Yes, if `a` is used to index an array, than the wrong bound check will lead to a, well, out-of-bounds access. What's the down-vote for?

Comment: From original poster's comments: "well, it's about accessing pixels with OpenCV. poxel(frame, pxfy, pxfx);". So yes, it might cause an out-of-bounds access and kill the process.

Comment: okay, I think I understand now :-) will see if I can optimize the code in other ways.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely it crashes because the condition evaluates to true even when a and b are out of range and there's probably resulting a memory access issue.

Comment: how would you solve it? I want to avoid the first expression..

Comment: @user1331044: The first expression is the only clear and accurate way to get both the operation and the meaning across, short of an `isBetween` function that'd still contain it.  (I might consider parentheses to set off the comparisons of each variable, but other than that, that's just *how you do it* in C++.)

Comment: unfortunately the first expression is lame while the second one speeded up my code so I wanted to use it elsewhere. Any other options here?  With parenthesis you mean this: if((0<=a<100) && (0<=b<200)) ? I tried that but also to no avail

Comment: @user1331044: The second one might be faster, but that doesn't mean much if it does completely the wrong thing.

Comment: @user1331044: No, "with parentheses" means adding them to the first expression to make its meaning slightly clearer: `if( (a>=0 && a<100) && (b>=0 && b<200) )`. As everyone keeps saying, you can't use the second expression because it doesn't do the comparisons you need.

Comment: okay then, guess I'll have to live with that I suppose :D

Answer (score -2):

`0<=x<200` doesn't do what you think it does in C++. C++ doesn't let you chain comparisons together like that, you need to do `0 <= x && x < 200`.

Comment: Because (1) you didn't answer the question ("why does it break?"), and (2) C++ *does* let you say `0 <= x < 200` (though the result is not at all what people with a math background would expect).  Not my downvote, but i'm considering it...

Comment: in another case it works though. But here it seems that when a or b are negative (e.g. a=-0.01) the first expression says no while the second one says okay and since accessing negative pixel coordinates is not possible it crashes. At least that's what I think

Comment: @user: If you're comparing in a range like this, then no, it doesn't *work*, it just "works".  :)  There's still brokenness there waiting for the right moment to come back and bite you in the ass.

Comment: @cHao (1) It broke because the OP thought C++ would let him to chain together two mathematical comparisons and effectively do a "between" comparison. (2) Indeed, C++ let's you chain together operators. But it doesn't let you "chain [mathematical] comparisons together like that".

Comment: @Hbcdev: It broke because it *did* chain them together (with unexpected results), rather than dying with a compile error.  So "C++ doesn't let you" is obviously wrong.  It just doesn't do what you usually mean when you do it.

Comment: @Hbcdev: Your answer does not explain. Essentially, it says the first expression does not work, C++ does not let you do it, and you need to do something else. By comparison, the upvoted answer explains. It states what the expression means (by using parentheses to show the compiler’s interpretation), it explains how it is evaluated (by stating the values resulting from the first operator and showing how they are used with the second operator), and it states how that causes a crash.